# Finish one sprite and start another in phaser

Tags: animation, phaser-framework

I am in the middle of developing very basic animation, 
**[a balloon rises up, bounces up a few times from the top screen and pops up]**
I got 2 separate spritesheets, one for balloon moving and another for pop. I did the first half of coding and now I am trying to figure out how to call another sprite to start the popping up
here is the code,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>hello phaser!</title>
        <script src="./phaser-2.6.2/build/phaser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
           var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', 
                      { preload: preload, create: create }
           );

         function preload ()
         {
             game.load.image('bg', 'assets/yellow-bg.png');//loads the bg image
             game.load.atlas('BlueAtlas',
                          './assets/balloonBlue_atlas.png',
                          './assets/balloonBlue.json'
             );   

             game.load.atlas('PopAtlas',
                       './assets/popB_atlas.png',
                       './assets/popB.json'
             );
        }

        var balloon;
        function create ()
        {
          this.background = this.add.tileSprite(
                  0,0, this.world.width, 
                  this.world.height, 'bg'
          );//loads bg

         //gravity
         game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

         //Set the world (global) gravity
         game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = -100;//negative makes the balloon go up

        //Sprite 2 is set to ignore the global gravity and use its own value
         balloon = game.add.sprite(300, 550, 'BlueAtlas'); //x and y starting point

         //Enable physics on those sprites
         game.physics.enable( balloon, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
         balloon.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
         balloon.body.bounce.y = 0.5;
         balloon.body.gravity.y = 50;

        function render()
        {
          game.debug.text('no gravity', sprite4.x - 32, 64);
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am a very beginner in this (started using Phaser yesterday) would you help me kindly? 
I have tried to follow some examples from internet but it is very advanced and it would be absolutely great to get some explanation together with it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Phaser actually has quite a nice tutorial (they usually do) for switching the spritesheet: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/animation/change-texture-on-click

I altered your code to demonstrate how to integrate the idea from the tutorial into your code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>hello phaser!</title>
        <script src="./phaser-2.6.2/build/phaser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
           var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', 
                      { preload: preload, create: create, update: update,render: render} 
                      //you'll need to add an 'update' function which you'll see 
                      //below, as well as add 'render' if you want that render function 
                      //you had below get called
           );

         function preload ()
         {
             game.load.image('bg', 'assets/yellow-bg.png');//loads the bg image
             game.load.atlas('BlueAtlas',
                          './assets/balloonBlue_atlas.png',
                          './assets/balloonBlue.json'
             );   

             game.load.atlas('PopAtlas',
                       './assets/popB_atlas.png',
                       './assets/popB.json'
             );
        }

        var balloon;
        function create ()
        {
          this.background = this.add.tileSprite(
                  0,0, this.world.width, 
                  this.world.height, 'bg'
          );//loads bg

         //gravity
         game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

         //Set the world (global) gravity
         game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = -100;//negative makes the balloon go up

        //Sprite 2 is set to ignore the global gravity and use its own value
         balloon = game.add.sprite(300, 550, 'BlueAtlas'); //x and y starting point

         //Enable physics on those sprites
         game.physics.enable( balloon, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
         balloon.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
         balloon.body.bounce.y = 0.5;
         balloon.body.gravity.y = 50;
      }

      function update() { //the update function that gets called every loop of the game
        if(balloon.body.position.y == 0) { //this will make the balloon pop once it hits 
            //the top of the screen, maybe not exactly when you want
            changeSpritesheet();//call the function to change the spritesheet used for 
            //you balloon
        }
      }

      function changeSpritesheet() {
        balloon.loadTexture('PopAtlas',0);//Load in the other spritesheet, you can pass 
        //other parameters, see http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Component.LoadTexture.
        //html#loadTexture
        balloon.animations.add('pop'); //Give the animation a name, see 
        //http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.AnimationManager.html#add 
        //for more parameters you can add
      }

      function render()//I noticed that this was inside your 'create' function, which 
      //I'm guessing you did not mean to do so I moved it out
        {
          //game.debug.text('no gravity', sprite4.x - 32, 64);//sprite4 isn't being used?
        }
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Phaser generally has great documentation and examples so always try to look for them! But I understand how sometimes (especially when you're just starting) it can be hard to figure out how to apply it to your code

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the comments, really helped!